# Correct use of IF BEGIN/END in a long SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to refresh some tables from production to UAT and hence create some scripts to check if @@Servername is UAT only then execute the scripts (since DBAs will be executing them). But when I'm testing the script, I see it is executing regardless of servername check. I believe it is due to GO statements. Is it Okay to remove the GO statements? Should I be replacing them with something?
Here is what the scripts look like:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
IF (@@ServerName = 'UAT_Servername') 
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE tbl_ABC DROP CONSTRAINT [tbl_ABC_constraint]
GO
/****** Object:  Table tbl_ABC    Script Date: 03/29/2023 01:30:41 PM ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'tbl_ABC') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE tbl_ABC
GO
/****** Object:  Table tbl_ABC    Script Date: 03/29/2023 01:30:41 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE tbl_ABC(
    [COLA] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [COLB] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COLC] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_COLB_COLC] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [COLC] ASC,
    [COLB] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_ABC ON 

INSERT tbl_ABC ([COLA], [COLB], [COLC]) VALUES (19, 17, N'ALL')
INSERT tbl_ABC ([COLA], [COLB], [COLC]) VALUES (29, 27, N'Australia')
...
--bunch of insert statements
...
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tbl_ABC OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE tbl_ABC ADD  CONSTRAINT [tbl_ABC_constraint]  DEFAULT ('QQQ') FOR [COLC]
GO
END -- I get error here 'Could not find stored procedure'
```

Comment: Please read about [GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-ver16) and do not assume anything about it's working.  In your case, stop using it.... ?

Comment: More explanation, see this DBFIDDLE (https://dbfiddle.uk/0015Yxkc), after seeing the results remove all use of `GO`, and then re-run the script.

Comment: Although if you have any `CREATE VIEW/TRIGGER/PROC` statements then you are stuck anyway.

Comment: I removed all GO statements.